# Mapreduce chaining values into a list for each key

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

i have a small project i am doing in mapreduce and since i am new with this i am running into alot of difficulties so would apreciate the help.
in this prjoect i have a file that contains a site and tag (there are 10 tags per site) i want to find for each site the simmilar sites by shared tags.
so for example of 3 sites this is my data set

```
site1   tag1
site1   tag2
site1   tag3
site1   tag4
site1   tag5
site2   tag1
site2   tag2
site2   tag3
site2   tag11
site2   tag12
site3   tag1
site3   tag11
site3   tag13
site3   tag14
site3   tag15
```

(i made just 5 for each site for this example).
what i am trying to do is do a mapreduce that key would be the tag and value the site.
i want for each tag to get a list (or array or whatever) of sites that have this tag 
so in this example:

```
tag1: site1, site2, site3
tag2: site1,site2
tag3: site1, site2
tag4: site1
```

and so on 
and then to  run over the lists and for each common pair give a vaule of 1 next to it so will look like this

```
tag1: site1_site2 1, site1_site3 1, site2_site3 1
tag2: site1_site2 1
```

and so on
and then chain another mapreduce job to sum the values for each pair
i wrote this code for it

```
public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text>{

    private Text site = new Text();
    private Text tag = new Text();
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) 
                       throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), "\t");
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            site.set(itr.nextToken());
            tag.set(itr.nextToken());
            context.write(tag, site);
        }
    }
}

public static class tagCount extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,Text> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) 
                             throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String res = "";
        while (values.iterator().hasNext()) {
            res = res + "," + values.iterator().next();
        }
        Text result = new Text(res);
        context.write(key, result);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "tag count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(tagCount.class);
    job.setReducerClass(tagCount.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

my first problem is how do i chain together the values in the reducer?
since now i just get a list of

```
tag1 site1
tag1 site2
```

and so on
i tried to set a string and when i iterate over values to add the next token to string but it is not working

thank you very much in advance for the help

Comment: To make my question more specific i want to know how i can iterate over all the values for certain key inside of the reducer.

Comment: ok i actually found out that my code does not even go to reducer function only the map function :(

Comment: Remove `job.setCombinerClass(tagCount.class);`. You dont want a combiner for this.

Comment: i removed it but i dont think noting has changed, it still does not enter the reducer function for some reason. (tried to print things from it nothing gets printed) and debug wont enter it

Comment: found the reasone it is not entering reducer i was using the wrong exten forgot to cange the IntWritable to Text :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a re-write of your reducer to get you started:

```
public static class TagCount extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {

    private IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text out = new Text();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) 
                         throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        List<String> sites = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Text t : values) {
            sites.add(t.toString());
        }

        for (int i=0; i<sites.size()-1; i++) {
            for (int j=i+1; j<sites.size(); j++) {
                out.set(sites.get(i) + "_" + sites.get(j))
                context.write(out, one);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Summary:

- You need to build an internal collection of the values. In this case i've used a List of Strings which is the safest way until you're comfortable with how Hadoop re-uses objects.
- This code assumes `sites` isn't going to be large, so an improvement would be adding some checking around its size, since we're putting it in memory and the following context.write will be expanding the data.
- You then iterate through sites and generate the permutations, writing each one out.
- Write the data out using `SequenceFileOutputFormat` and then your following job can use `SequenceFileInputFormat` and the types entering the mapper will be `Text` and `IntWritable`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the Help it really pushed me forward i wrote what you said and when i debug it in console it works great but when i look at file it is empty for some reason the context.write inside the For is not working or overwriting itself i think

Comment: Make sure you have `job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);`

Comment: First of all i really wanted to say thank you for taking the time out to help i appreciate it alot.

Comment: was to long for comment so put it in answer
@Binary